# Issue with splitting xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Alright all,

I'm having a slight issue trying to get this xslt to work. I'm just starting out with xslt so i've only got the basics working at the moment. Any help would be great.

**Sample XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order_Root>
   <Header>
      <Info>Some Info</Info>
   </Header>
   <Order Number="1" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000" />
   </Order>
   <Order Number="2" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000" />
   </Order>
   <Order Number="3" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000" />
   </Order>
</Order_Root>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Orders_Root/Header/Order">
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{@Number}.xml">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently this xslt splits the xml into 3 xml containing the Order and the filename as the @Number.

This is ok however i'm struggling with trying to put the Header into each xml.

**So resulting in 3 xml files:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order_Root>
   <Header>
      <Info>Some Info</Info>
   </Header>
   <Order Number="1" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000" />
   </Order>
</Order_Root>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order_Root>
   <Header>
      <Info>Some Info</Info>
   </Header>
   <Order Number="2" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000" />
   </Order>
</Order_Root>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order_Root>
   <Header>
      <Info>Some Info</Info>
   </Header>
   <Order Number="3" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000" />
   </Order>
</Order_Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you move to XSLT 3 you can change

```
<xsl:template match="/Orders_Root/Header/Order">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{@Number}.xml">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="/Orders_Root/Header/Order">
    <xsl:variable name="order" select="."/>
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{@Number}.xml">
        <xsl:copy select="/*">
          <xsl:copy-of select="Header, $order"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Obviously with XSLT 2 if you know the root name you can use

```
<xsl:template match="/Orders_Root/Header/Order">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{@Number}.xml">
      <Order_Root>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/*/Header, ." />
      </Order_Root>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: brilliant mate appreciate it

Comment: Hi martin, I am using xslt 2, what do you mean by if i know the root name? I have tried running the xslt that you provided but it doesn't seem to split the xml?

Comment: I tried to point out that the attempt to use `<xsl:copy select="/*">` would copy and create a root element the same as the input while `<Order_Root>` would create a certain root element hardcoded in the stylesheet. As for the code not working, that might be your fault :), your input sample has `Order_Root` while the template you said that splits and that I copied has `/Orders_Root` with an `s` after `Order`. So that template can't match the input you posted.

Comment: Haha oops. Cheers Martin. One more thing if you don't mind. If the header end tag was to move to the bottom like the example I have pasted above. what change would be needed to make that work?

Comment: I have seen your edit but you should edit your question with various of your input sample, not answers. As for that changed sample where you simply want to extract the subtree of each `Order`, in XSLT 3 you could easily do that with `<xsl:copy-of select="root(snapshot())"/>` instead of the `<xsl:copy-of select="." />`.  And in XSLT 2 you can of course spell out `<Order><Header Info="{@Info}"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></Header></Order>`.

Comment: apologies martin will remember that for next time. What if there was more than one attribute in the Header element?

Comment: Well, the suggested XSLT 3 solution will work in any case, independent of the number of nesting levels, independent of the element names and the name or number of attributes. And Saxon 9.8 (all editions) as well as Exselt 1.1 as well as Altova 2017R3 and 2018 do support XSLT 3 so consider to  use that version. If you want to reconstruct the hierarchy with XSLT 2 then in general you need to reprocess the tree in another mode, if you don't know how to do that then ask another question.

Comment: I have not been successful yet i will ask another question, cheers for your help.